# XML Parsing Error when using Require.js

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, antlr, antlr4, codemirror

I'm trying to integrate my JavaScript ANTLR4 parser with my CodeMirror based text editor. I investigated on how to integrate the parser and wrote the following code:

```
// Parser
    var antlr4 = require('antlr4/index');

    // load nodejs compatible require
    var ace_require = require;
    require = undefined;
    var Honey = { 'requirePath': [] }; // walk up to js folder, see Honey docs
    importScripts("lib/require.js");
    var antlr4_require = require;
    require = ace_require;

    // load antlr4 and myLanguage
    var antlr4, Lexer ,Parser;
    try {
        require = antlr4_require;
        antlr4 = require('antlr4/index');
        Lexer = require('generated-parser/SparkS_v2Lexer');
        Parser = require('generated-parser/SparkS_v2Parser');
    } finally {
        require = ace_require;
    }

    // class for gathering errors and posting them to the editor
    var AnnotatingErrorListener = function(annotations) {
        antlr4.error.ErrorListener.call(this);
        this.annotations = annotations;
        return this;
    };

    AnnotatingErrorListener.prototype = Object.create(antlr4.error.ErrorListener.prototype);
    AnnotatingErrorListener.prototype.constructor = AnnotatingErrorListener;

    AnnotatingErrorListener.prototype.syntaxError = function(recognizer, offendingSymbol, line, column, msg, e) {
        this.annotations.push({
            row: line - 1,
            column: column,
            text: msg,
            type: "error"
    });
    };

    var validate = function(input) {
        var stream = new antlr4.InputStream(input);
        var lexer = new Lexer.SparkS_v2Lexer(stream);
        var tokens = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        var parser = new Parser.SparkS_v2Parser(tokens);
        var annotations = [];
        var listener = new AnnotatingErrorListener(annotations)
        parser.removeErrorListeners();
        parser.addErrorListener(listener);
        parser.parseMyRule();
        return annotations;
    };

    editor.on("keyup", function() {
        console.log(validate(editor.getValue()));
    })
```

To load the parser, I'm using "require.js" library of Torben Haase's Honey project based on [this](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/ace-javascript-target.md) tutorial. However, I'm getting the following and other XML parsing errors for the each "required" file:

```
Uncaught Error: Honey: unable to load 0:antlr4/index (0 )
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: file:///home/enes/Desktop/git/text_editor_mirror/antlr4/index.js Line Number 1, Column 1:
ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined
```

So, how can I solve these errors?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:requirejs] tag to refer to anything else than [this software](http://requirejs.org/).